# JLabel not show

Tags: java, colors, jlabel, exit

I have got a few problems.
1. I want to show message before exit. Click button and message show and after 0,5 second program exit and open next program. 
2. I want to change color; in first app color is correct but in next color is default.
Can you modify this or told my step by step how to do this? Thanks for any help :).

Code of first program:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class Start extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
JButton Polski, English; //nazwy przycisków
JLabel jezyk, language;
static JLabel wybór;

public Start()
{
    setSize(330,170);//rozmiar
    setTitle("MathCalc v0.1 by Majkel");
    setLayout(null);

    jezyk = new JLabel("Choose language:");
    jezyk.setBounds(40,10,200,40);
    add(jezyk);

    Polski = new JButton("Polski");
    Polski.setBounds(40,50,100,30);
    add(Polski);
    Polski.addActionListener(this);

    English = new JButton("English");
    English.setBounds(150,50,100,30);
    add(English);
    English.addActionListener(this);

    wybór = new JLabel("Choose");
    wybór.setBounds(40,90,400,30);
    add(wybór);


}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Choose language:");
    Start okno1 = new Start();

    okno1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    okno1.setVisible(true);
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    Object klik = e.getSource();
    if(klik==Polski)
    {   
        wybór.setText("Wybrałeś język Polski.".toString()); //I want to show this massage before exit, but it not show
        System.out.println("Wybrałeś język Polski."); //This show corect in console

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            this.setVisible(false);
            new czynnośćPL().setVisible(true);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

    }

    else if(klik==English)
    {
        wybór.setText("You have chosen English.".toString()); //I want to show this massage before exit, but it not show
        System.out.println("You have chosen English."); //This show corect in console

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            this.setVisible(false);
            new czynnośćPL().setVisible(true);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

    }
}


}
```

And second program:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class czynnośćPL extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
JButton pole, obwód, objętość; //nazwy przycisków
JLabel Wybór, oblicz;


public czynnośćPL()
{


    setSize(400,200);//rozmiar
    setTitle("MathCalc v0.1 by Majkel");
    setLayout(null);
    setBackground(Color.blue);

    oblicz = new JLabel("Oblicz:");
    oblicz.setBounds(40,10,200,40);
    add(oblicz);

    pole = new JButton("pole");
    pole.setBounds(40,50,100,30);
    add(pole);
    pole.addActionListener(this);

    obwód = new JButton("obwód");
    obwód.setBounds(150,50,100,30);
    add(obwód);
    obwód.addActionListener(this);

    objętość = new JButton("objętość");
    objętość.setBounds(260,50,100,30);
    add(objętość);
    objętość.addActionListener(this);


}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Start okno1 = new Start();
    okno1.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(189,189,189));
    okno1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    okno1.setVisible(true);


}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    Object klik = e.getSource();
    if(klik==pole)
    {
        System.out.println("Wybrałeś pole.");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            this.setVisible(false);
            new polePL().setVisible(true);//co ma open
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    else if(klik==obwód)
    {
        System.out.println("Wybrałeś obwód.");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            this.setVisible(false);
            new czynnośćPL().setVisible(true);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    else if(klik==objętość)
    {
        System.out.println("Wybrałeś objętość.");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            this.setVisible(false);
            new czynnośćPL().setVisible(true);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Sorry this isn't a coding service.  You have to provide effort and show us what you have tried

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). - please respect the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).
 Also please translate your code to english.

Comment: try calling revalidate() after setting the JLabel's new value

Comment: This not work any ideas?

Comment: Now it work. I use "super.update(this.getGraphics());" thanks for any help but I have a small problem with color of JFrame it doesn't change :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `javax.swing.Timer` to run task on gui thread after special delay:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(milliseconds, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                hideMessageDialog();
                Start.this.setVisible(false);
                new czynnośćPL().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
```

`milliseconds` set delay before first task is executed and delay between task is executed periodically. By calling `timer.setRepeats(false);` you tell `Timer` to execute your task only once. Task is `actionPerformed` method of `ActionListener`.

And to change background color of JFrame you do:

```
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
```

You did this in another main method. Full `Start` class is:

```
package com.stackoverflow.main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Start extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JButton Polski, English; // nazwy przycisków
    JLabel jezyk, language;
    static JLabel wybór;
    private JDialog messageDialog;
    private JLabel messageLabel;

    public Start() {
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        setSize(330, 170);// rozmiar
        setTitle("MathCalc v0.1 by Majkel");
        setLayout(null);

        messageDialog = new JDialog(this);
        messageLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
        messageDialog.setSize(200, 200);
        messageDialog.getContentPane().add(messageLabel);

        jezyk = new JLabel("Choose language:");
        jezyk.setBounds(40, 10, 200, 40);
        add(jezyk);

        Polski = new JButton("Polski");
        Polski.setBounds(40, 50, 100, 30);
        add(Polski);
        Polski.addActionListener(this);

        English = new JButton("English");
        English.setBounds(150, 50, 100, 30);
        add(English);
        English.addActionListener(this);

        wybór = new JLabel("Choose");
        wybór.setBounds(40, 90, 400, 30);
        add(wybór);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Choose language:");
        Start okno1 = new Start();

        okno1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        okno1.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object klik = e.getSource();
        if (klik == Polski) {
            wybór.setText("Wybrałeś język Polski.".toString());
            hideThisShowNewFrameAfterDelay(1500);
            showMessageDialog("Wybrałeś język Polski");
            System.out.println("Wybrałeś język Polski.");
        }

        else if (klik == English) {
            wybór.setText("You have chosen English.".toString());
            hideThisShowNewFrameAfterDelay(1500);
            showMessageDialog("You have chosen English.");
            System.out.println("You have chosen English.");
        }
    }

    private void showMessageDialog(String message) {
        messageLabel.setText(message);
        messageDialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void hideMessageDialog() {
        messageDialog.dispose();
    }

    private void hideThisShowNewFrameAfterDelay(int milliseconds) {
        Timer timer = new Timer(milliseconds, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                hideMessageDialog();
                Start.this.setVisible(false);
                new czynnośćPL().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot all is working now :) and I'm happy :)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class Start extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
JButton Polski, English; //nazwy przycisków
JLabel jezyk, language, wybór;

public Start()
{
getContentPane().setBackground(new Color (189, 189, 189));  
setSize(330,170);//rozmiar
setTitle("MathCalc v0.1 by Majkel");
setLayout(null);

jezyk = new JLabel("Choose language:");
jezyk.setBounds(40,10,200,40);
add(jezyk);

Polski = new JButton("Polski");
Polski.setBounds(40,50,100,30);
add(Polski);
Polski.addActionListener(this);

English = new JButton("English");
English.setBounds(150,50,100,30);
add(English);
English.addActionListener(this);

wybór = new JLabel("Choose");
wybór.setBounds(40,90,400,30);
add(wybór);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
System.out.println("Choose language:");
Start okno = new Start();
okno.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
okno.setVisible(true);
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
Object klik = e.getSource();
if(klik==Polski)
{   
    wybór.setText("Wybrałeś język Polski.".toString()); 
    System.out.println("Wybrałeś język Polski."); 
    super.update(this.getGraphics());
    try {
        Thread.sleep(600);
        this.setVisible(false);
        new czynnośćPL().setVisible(true);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

}

else if(klik==English)
{
    wybór.setText("You have chosen English.".toString());
    System.out.println("You have chosen English."); 
    super.update(this.getGraphics());
    try {
        Thread.sleep(600);
        this.setVisible(false);
        new czynnośćPL().setVisible(true);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

}
}

}
```